# Preventing a hierarchy of classes from being created on the stack

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, destructor

I'm not sure if this is possible.

I need to prevent a all classes derived from X from being instantiated as local stack or member variables. I made all their destructors protected and this did the trick as far as outside scopes are concerned. However I need to prevent them from being instantiated by themselves, too. I mean if Y has member variables of type Z or instantiates local variables of type Z in its methods, thid doesn't cut it.

Now I could create private destructors in all the leaves of the hierarchy tree, but the problem is that every not should be allowed to be a (heap) variable. In the case X <- Y <- Z, all three should be instantiated but X and Y cannot have private destructors. Moreover even that doesn't stop me from having local variables of type Z in the methods of Z.

I guess by making their constructors private and adding operator new as friend to all of them will do the trick, but this is a LOT of extra work (since we use several versions of operator new) and the hierarchy is big.

So, is there a way of having a (preferably) compile-time, or a runtime error for stack instantiation of these objects, whithout resorting to the private-constructors-friend-new-way?

<edit>
The thing is that the previous programmers of this project wrote a ton of code and all classes in this hierarchy have terribly complicated destructors. And also, the authors indiscriminately called virtual methods in those destructros, which lead to a lot of unexplicable (to them) crashes and memory corruptions. Now converted all destructors to a `obj->Release()` pattern and in the top-most Release I have `delete this`. Obviously this wont work for stack objects and now I introduced some crashes of my own. Also I'm kinda short of time and the *run/wait for crash/fix this specific crash* method is very very slow
</edit>

Comment: I think where the variables located is depend on how you declared it?

Comment: An object should normally not care how it is stored. That violates the single-responsibility idiom. What you're asking is a serious abuse of the language, so I wouldn't expect an answer to be pretty.

Answer (score 0):

In his book “More Effective C++” in item 27, Scott Meyers (incidentally my favorite author on C++) describes why it’s not possible in the general sense and within the bounds of portable or semi-portable C++ to definitively distinguish whether an object has been allocated on the stack, heap, or is statically allocated. It also discusses various options for ensuring an object can only be allocated on the stack, or on the heap.  One of those is more or less do-able, the other doesn't have a truly portable foolproof way of working; I forget which is which. (Book is at work, I'm at home.)